# I'm trying to apply the transition effect to this list item so it can slide out on a button click that reveals the menu

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, transition, translate

I am trying to get all the list items to slide out on a button click (the button has state)
I can't figure out why the code does not make the animation work, when I click the button all the list items are already all the way out as if the animation was completed.
This is the link to the github code, it's linked to the file in which this code is located: https://github.com/radosav-perisic/portfolio-website/blob/main/src/components/Navbar.jsx.

I am using Tailwind.css to style the components and I want to have this effect for the mobile version of my app since as you can see, I have the large screen properties on the other end of the `:` operator.
Here is the code, I will only provide the code of only one list item

```html
<div
  className={
    social
      ? "lg:flex fixed flex-col top-[35%] left-0"
      : "hidden lg:flex fixed flex-col top-[35%] left-0"
  }
>
  <ul>
    <li
      className={
        social
          ? `w-[140px] h-[45px] flex justify-between items-center ml-[-100px] ${
              social
                ? "transform transition-all translate-x-24 duration-300"
                : null
            } bg-blue-600`
          : "w-[160px] h-[60px] flex justify-between items-center ml-[-100px] hover:ml-[-10px] duration-300 bg-blue-600"
      }
    >
      <a
        className="flex justify-between items-center w-full text-gray-300"
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/radosav-perisic-58ab96265/"
      >
        Linkedin <FaLinkedin size={social ? 20 : 30} />
      </a>
    </li>
    //...
  </ul>
</div>;
```

I tried various combinations of tailwind css properties to make the effect work and nothing worked so far.

Comment: can you please post your code on stackblitz or codesandbox and then share the link here?

Comment: here is the github link for the project code: https://github.com/radosav-perisic/portfolio-website